# Shared Vue component: CSS has to be manually imported by the client

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I built a shared Vue component using TypeScript. After the build, it generated a separate CSS file. When the client imports this component, the CSS is not imported automatically. It has to be explicitly imported. How can we let the client automatically import it? What's wrong in my configuration? Here is the [source code](https://github.com/jianwu/msplit)

For example:

```
import msplit from 'msplit';
import 'msplit/dist/lib/lib.css';

Vue.use(msplit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Vue CLI project, CSS is extracted to a separate file by default in a production build.

You could disable this feature with [`css.extract=false`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract) in [`<projectRoot>/vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js):

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot. Just curious, any reason why this is by default to true for production. Is it because of performance?

Comment: @JianwuChen No problem :) See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43424122/6277151)